# If I have 2 spinners and one is open, if I try to open the other it doesn't open on first click. Is there a way to fix that?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have **few spinners** in a **Linearlayout**. When I click first one to open it, I'd like to be able to click another one and have that click close the first one and open the second one.

But that's not what happens now. I have to click the second one **twice** to get it to open.

I've tried googling but couldn't find anything relevant. Here is the below image reference

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To understand how to use this site, you may take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and pages they link to. In particular, it will help if a question like this has code, as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the problem.  Please include the code sample as text.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer your question without specific code snippets, but I will suggest you check whether you have implemented the click listeners for your spinners correctly, and when a spinner is clicked, it should toggle its open/close state.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have two spinners open at the same time.
First time you click you are selecting/dismissing opened spinner, and only then you are able to open next one.

It is standard Android platform behavior.

Comment: It sounds like you're understanding my question, but just to hold out hope, you're saying there's no way to set up 2 spinners so that when one is open, clicking another will close the open one and open the one that was just clicked on?

So 2 spinners would never be open at the same time. I just want one click to close one and open another.

Comment: you would need to create custom solutions for that, I don't know of any library that could help with that. Also i would suggest not to change that behavior as user on this platform is used to things work like that.